# Finding the top 10 and converting it from centimeters to inches - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading data from file, like listed below, it is a .dat file:

```
1
Carmella Henderson
24.52
13.5
21.76
2
Christal Piper
14.98
11.01
21.75
3
Erma Park
12.11
13.51
18.18
4
Dorita Griffin
20.05
10.39
21.35
```

The file itself contains 50 records. From this data I need the person number, name and the first number, like so:

```
1 #person number
Marlon Holmes  #Name
18.86 # First number
13.02 # Second Number
13.36 # Third Number
```

I already have code to read the data however I unable to get the top 10 results based on the #First number

The #First number in the Top 10 currently is in centimeters but needs to be converted to inches, I am unsure on how to combine the top 10 and conversion into one alongside the reading of the data

Code that reads the data:

```
 with open('veggies_2016.txt', 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        excess_count = 0
        for line in f:
            if count < 3:
                print(line)
                count += 1
            elif count == 3 and excess_count < 1:
                excess_count += 1
            else:
                count = 0
                excess_count = 0
```

As mentioned the code reads the file, like so #Person number, #name and #first number, but #first number needs to be converted to inches and then all of the data needs to be sorted to find the top 10

This process will also have to be repeated for #second number and #third number however they are separate in terms of their code from #first number

I have tried to read the data then append to a list and sort it and convert it from that but with no success, any help would be appreciated

Whole code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint
def menu():
    exit = False


    while not exit:
        print("To enter new competitior data, type new")
        print("To view the competition score boards, type Scoreboard")
        print("To view the Best Overall Growers Scoreboard, type Podium")
        print("To review this years and previous data, type Data review")
        print("Type quit to exit the program")

        choice = raw_input("Which option would you like?")

        if choice == 'new':
            new_competitor()
        elif choice == 'Scoreboard':
            scoreboard_menu()
        elif choice == 'Podium':
            podium_place()
        elif choice == 'Data review':
            data_review()
        elif choice == 'quit':
            print("Goodbye")
            raise SystemExit

"""Entering new competitor data: record competitor's name and vegtables lengths"""

def competitor_data():
    global competitor_num
    l = []

    print("How many competitors would you like to enter?")

    competitors = raw_input("Number of competitors:")

    num_competitors = int(competitors)

    for i in range(num_competitors):

        name = raw_input("Enter competitor name:")
        Cucumber = raw_input("Enter length of Cucumber:")
        Carrot = raw_input("Enter length of Carrot:")
        Runner_Beans = raw_input("Enter length of Runner Beans:")

        l.append(competitor_num)
        l.append(name)
        l.append(Cucumber)
        l.append(Carrot)
        l.append(Runner_Beans)

        competitor_num += 1

    return (l)
def new_competitor():
    with open('veggies_2016.txt', 'a') as f:
        for item in competitor_data():
            f.write("%s\n" %(item))
def scoreboard_menu():
    exit = False

    print("Which vegetable would you like the scoreboard for?")

    vegetable = raw_input("Please type either Cucumber, Carrot or Runner Beans:")

    if vegetable == "Cucumber":
        Cucumber_Scoreboard()
    elif vegetable == "Carrot":
        Carrot_Scoreboard()
    elif vegetable == "Runner Beans":
        Runner_Beans_Scoreboard()

def Cucumber_Scoreboard():
    exit = True

    print("Which year would you like the Scoreboard from?")

    scoreboard = raw_input("Please type a year:")

    if scoreboard == "2015":
        cucumber_veg_2015()
    elif scoreboard == "2014":
        cucumber_veg_2014()
    elif scoreboard == "2016":
        cucumber_veg_2016()


def cucumber_veg_2016(cm):
    return float(cm) / 2.54

names = OrderedDict([('Competitor Number', int),
                     ('Competitor Name', str),
                     ('Cucumber', cucumber_veg_2016),
                     ('Carrot', float),
                     ('Runner Bean', float)])
data = []
with open('veggies_2016.txt') as fobj:
    while True:
        item = {}
        try:
            for name, func in names.items():
                item[name] = func(next(fobj).strip())
            data.append(item)
        except StopIteration:
            break

pprint.pprint(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Cucumber'))[:10])
```

Comment: Far too much code. See how to ask a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Reading the data into a list of dictionaries would work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint

def to_inch(cm):
    return float(cm) / 2.54

names = OrderedDict([('person_number', int),
                     ('name', str),
                     ('first', to_inch),
                     ('second', float),
                     ('third', float)])
data = []
with open('veggies_2016.txt') as fobj:
    while True:
        item = {}
        try:
            for name, func in names.items():
                item[name] = func(next(fobj).strip())
            data.append(item)
        except StopIteration:
            break

pprint.pprint(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('first'))[:10])
```

Output:

```
[{'first': 4.76771653543307,
  'name': 'Erma Park',
  'person_number': 3,
  'second': 13.51,
  'third': 18.18},
 {'first': 5.897637795275591,
  'name': 'Christal Piper',
  'person_number': 2,
  'second': 11.01,
  'third': 21.75},
 {'first': 7.893700787401575,
  'name': 'Dorita Griffin',
  'person_number': 4,
  'second': 10.39,
  'third': 21.35},
 {'first': 9.653543307086613,
  'name': 'Carmella Henderson',
  'person_number': 1,
  'second': 13.5,
  'third': 21.76}]
```

## In Steps

This helper function converts centimeters into inches:

```
def to_inch(cm):
    return float(cm) / 2.54
```

We use an ordered dictionary to hold the names for the different items we want to read in order. The value is a function that we use to convert the read value for each item:

```
names = OrderedDict([('person_number', int),
                     ('name', str),
                     ('first', to_inch),
                     ('second', float),
                     ('third', float)])
```

We start with an empty list:

```
data = []
```

And open our file:

```
with open('veggies_2016.txt') as fobj:
```

We do something without a defined end and create a new dictionary `item` each time:

```
    while True:
        item = {}
```

We try to read from the file until it is finished, i.e. until we get a
`StopIteration` exception:

```
        try:
            for name, func in names.items():
                item[name] = func(next(fobj).strip())
            data.append(item)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

We go through the keys and values of our order dictionary `names` and call each
value, i.e. the function `func()` on the next line we retrieve with `next()`.
This converts the entry into the desired datatype and does the cm-inch conversion for `first`. After reading all items for one person, we append the dictionary to the list `data`.

Finally, we sort by the key `first` and print out the 10 to entries
(my example file has less than 10 entries):

```
pprint.pprint(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('first'))[:10])
```

## Integration with your code:

You need to put the code into the function `podium_place()`:

```
def cucumber_veg_2016(cm):
    return float(cm) / 2.54

def podium_place():
    names = OrderedDict([('Competitor Number', int),
                         ('Competitor Name', str),
                         ('Cucumber', cucumber_veg_2016),
                         ('Carrot', float),
                         ('Runner Bean', float)])
    data = []
    with open('veggies_2016.txt') as fobj:
        while True:
            item = OrderedDict()
            try:
                for name, func in names.items():
                    item[name] = func(next(fobj).strip())
                data.append(item)
            except StopIteration:
                break

    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Cucumber'), reverse=True)
    for entry in sorted_data[:10]:
        for key, value in entry.items():
            print key, value
        print

menu()
```

At the end you need to call `menu()`. Also, if top mean largest first, you need sort `reverse` (see above).

Comment: tried running this however it prints the list before the main menu

Comment: Just put this code after the main menu. BTW, there is nor main menu in your question above.

Comment: Maybe the menu is in a function and you call this function after the code for reading the file content. It is really hard to debug code you cannot see. ;) BTW, does the code work and produce the right output?

Comment: Ill add my whole code, and it sort of works, its printing in the wrong order for some reason

Comment: Hopefully that helps

Comment: managed to fix it, however cant seem to fix the printing order

Comment: Are using this line: `pprint.pprint(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Cucumber'), reverse=True)[:10])`? Note the `reverse`.

Comment: i hadnt the reverse in but it still prints out like:

{'Carrot': 32.2,
  'Competitor Name': 'Test1',
  'Competitor Number': 1,
  'Cucumber': 1.7716535433070866,
  'Runner Bean': 3.4},

Comment: I get `'Cucumber': 9.653543307086613,` in the first entry, using the data in your question. With the `reverse`.

Comment: would there be a reason why its doing this, as it sorts the correct one but 'Carrot' is always at the top?

Comment: Ok. That is what you want. Dictionaries do not preserve order. I changed `item = {}` into `item = OrderedDict()`. Modify your code and try again.

Comment: Thanks, also BTW is there a way for it not too print OrderDict() and just print the values

Comment: Just use `print value` instead of `print key, value` (see my answer). BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would read them as a record at a time. You can put that functionality in a function that you call several times with the same file. It can return a `None` when you reach the end of the file. It will return a tuple with all values for a given record (including conversions). You can then use `sorted` to sort the list of records using any one of the values from each record.

```
def read_record(fid):
    id = fid.readline()

    # At the end of the file
    if id is None:
        return None

    name = fid.readline()

    # Perform the conversion
    number1_inches = float(fid.readline()) / 2.54
    number2 = float(fid.readline())
    number3 = float(fid.readline())

    return (id, name, number1_inches, number2, number3)

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fid:
    records = list()

    while True
        new_record = read_record(fid)

        # Stop if we hit the end of the file
        if new_record is None:
            break

        records.append(new_record)

    # Now sort the records based on the value of number1
    records = sorted(records, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: when i try this i get a error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: