# Ordered dictionary Sum and Top 3 of the Ordered dictionary sum

Tags: python, python-2.7

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235070/finding-the-top-10-and-converting-it-from-centimeters-to-inches-python), I am trying to sum values within an `OrderedDict`:

```
names = OrderedDict([('Competitor Number', int),
        ('Competitor Name', str),
        ('Cucumber', to_inch),
        ('Carrot', to_inch),
        ('Runner Bean', to_inch)])
```

How can I sum the cucumber, carrot and runner bean values together?

`to_inch` is just a cm to inches conversion .

Below is whole code surrounding this area with the order dict and the code to read from the file:

```
data = []
names = OrderedDict([('Competitor Number', int),
    ('Competitor Name', str),
    ('Cucumber', to_inch),
    ('Carrot', to_inch),
    ('Runner Bean', to_inch)])

with open('veggies_2015.dat') as fobj:
    while True:
        item = {}
        try:
            for name, func in names.items():
                item[name] = func(next(fobj).strip())
            data.append(item)
        except StopIteration:
            break
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('Runner Bean'), reverse = True)
for entry in sorted_data[:3]:
    for key, value in entry.items():
        print value
    print
```

I have tried using this solution but to no success `sum(item['Competitor Name'] for item in data)`

I can currently get the top 3 results however it is based off one of the results in this instance Runner Bean, however it should be based the sum of Cucumber, carrot and runner bean together to get the top 3

Any help would be appreciated

veggies_2015.dat format:

```
1 
Marlon Holmes 
18.86 
13.02 
13.36
```

its like this for 50 records

Comment: what `veggies_2015.dat`' content looks like?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36261916/edit) your question to add that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different key function for sorting:

```
def by_veg_sum(record):
    return sum(record[entry] for entry in ['Cucumber','Carrot','Runner Bean'])
```

and use it in your code:

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=by_veg_sum, reverse=True)
```

You can add a debug print to the see the calculated sum:

```
def by_veg_sum(record):
    s = sum(record[entry] for entry in ['Cucumber','Carrot','Runner Bean'])
    print s
    return s
```

If you want to add the actual sum to records, you can do this:

```
for record in data:
    record['sum'] = sum(record[entry] for entry in
                        ['Cucumber','Carrot','Runner Bean'])
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('sum'), reverse=True)
```

Print selected values for each record just like from an ordinary dictionary:

```
for entry in sorted_data[:10]:
    for key in ['Competitor Number', 'Competitor Name', 'sum']:
        print entry[key]
    print
```

Comment: the code doesn't seem to add together the cucumber, Carrot and Runner Bean values

Comment: Die you try it? The entry with highest value for the sim will be first. No? It uses the sum of three as sorting criterion. Try adding a print In `by_veg_sum`, printing the sum before returning it and you will what it is doing.

Comment: it does return the highest sum yes, however it prints the converted values and not the actual sum itself

Comment: Added a variation that also adds the sum to each record.

Comment: how do i get it though to just print the name, person number and the sum and nothing else?

Comment: You can use each record in your data list just like a normal dict. See my updated answer.